# find the first instance of a 2 character repeating segment in a string

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to find the first instance of a 2 character repeating segment in a string. so if the string is abcdabcd i would want it to return "ab". i think i need a nested while loop but cannot figure out what is wrong with how i am approaching.

```
i = 0
j = (i+2)
k = (i+1)
m = (k+2)
a = newstr[i:j]
b = newstr[k:m]
while i < len(newstr)-2:
    while k < len(newstr)-1:
        if a == b:
        print (a)

i +=1
```

---

separately i tested out while loop with a very simple loop and even that isn't working- what am i doing wrong in both the above and the below? THANKS!!

```
i = 0
j = i + 2
a = newstr[i:j]
while i < len(newstr)-2:
    if a == "15":
        print (a)
i +=1
```

Comment: The statement `i +=1` in not in the loop. Change the indentation.

Comment: use for-loop instead of while-loop and use *string.count()* to check the number of instances of your segment